# Move data between EventHubs in different regions

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have webapps spread out in a number of different regions. Each app put data in a region-local event hub. After this I want to collect all the data in a central event hub so I can do processing of all the data in one place. What is the best way to move data from one event hub to another? The different regions have on the order of 1000 messages per second they need to put into the hubs.

Ideas I have tried:

1. Let the webapp write directly to the central event hub. The downside is that the connection between regions can be bad. Every day I would get a lot of timeouts between southeast Asia and north Europe.
2. Use a stream analytics job to move from one to the other. This seems to work ok, except that it is not 100% reliable with high load. My job stopped for no reason and had to be manually restarted (after 15 minutes of downtime) to work again.

Comment: Why not process them in their own region or directly send it to the centralized region? It would matter for costs..

Comment: I need the data in a central event hub to stream it into a database located in the central region. So something must move the data there, question is what?

Comment: Why not enable Capture on your event hub and get the data from multiple event hubs to a common central storage and aggregate on that?

Comment: For batch processing its a great idea. However, I have a realtime database (druid) to which I want to stream data with spark streaming.

Answer (score 1):

While my first answer would have been to try your #2 above, it didn't work for you (for whatever reason, I haven't tried Stream Analytics myself), you pretty much know what you have to do: copy data from one event hub to the other.

Thus write an EventHub consumer that copies the message from one EventHub to another potentially wrapping it in an envelope if you need to bring some of the metadata along with it (enqueued time for example). If your destination event hub goes down, just keep retrying and don't commit progress until you succeed in sending the message over (since unless you parse the bodies you shouldn't have poison messages). No matter which solution you use you're going to have duplicate messages arrive in the central eventhub so plan for that by including unique ids inside the payload or designing the matter otherwise.

Obviously ensure that you have enough partitions on the central Event Hub to handle the load from all the other ones and you'll certainly want local partitions since 1000/second is the per partition write limit.

You'll still have the choice to make of whether to put the copier locally or centrally, my inclination is locally but you can test it both ways with the same code (though your commit/offset tracker should probably be in the same place as the copier runs).

So yeah stuff can go down, just make sure to start it up again preferably automatically when it does (and put in monitoring on how far behind your copying processes are). It'd be great if Stream Analytics did it reliably enough, but alas.

You also have choices as to how partitions are assigned to copier workers. Constant assignment is not a *bad* choice if the workers are guaranteed to start up again quickly (ie are on managed thing that will keep X alive). The auto assignment of partitions seems somewhat likely to lead to partitions that are forgotten for brief periods of time before rebalancing but just choose your poison.

Comment: When you say write an EventHub consumer, do you mean a regular App service WebJob? Im doing some experiments with that now, but I have difficulty getting good performance to write to the central location. I tried with a IAsyncCollector output binding and it took 20+ sec to write 200 messages.

Comment: I haven't used enough of the various Azure PAAS things to have a good idea of what  that ends up looking like. When I've used event hubs I've been running C#/.NET (or Java) on servers or in a docker container that processes things continuously. Things that come to mind to check are: Are you committing offsets too often, are you spinning up a connection on every request or reusing one etc. Basically write it the same way you would in your server code where you send the data the first place, and in your processing code centrally. (Though if you're not doing it with code that's not much help.)

Comment: Another thing to consider is poking Azure Support to see why the Stream Analytics job that seems like it ought to work shutdown.

Comment: For the webjob Im using the built in EventHub output binding for output writing, so I hope its done in a efficient way. My setup was `EH (asia) -> webjob (asia) -> EH (europe)`. But maybe its quicker to read than to write so I should put the webjob in the destination region instead?